# How does a browser determine which objects to request?

Tags: html, browser, tags, request

When a browser receives the initial root HTML page, how does it determine exactly which other objects should be requested.  Is there a list of HTML tags that the browser will always request the associated content from the server when they are detected?

I realize the need to implement an HTML parser for this, however I am not sure of all the individual tags and attributes that are important.

Comment: Browsers don't request tags; they request files specified by URLs. And sometimes they parse documents (HTML, XML, SVG...) that refer to other assets (XSLT, CSS, JS, images, fonts, multimedia, flash files, java applets, other HTML files, etc.) that also need to be downloaded, and some of these assets can also refer to other additional assets. If you want to know how this happens, you'll need to read these document format specifications.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320239/how-does-browser-detect-embedded-web-content-from-a-html-page/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers parse the HTML, and know which elements (with which attributes) require additional resources to be loaded.

i.e. They implement an HTML parser.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question some to remove ambiguity.  I realize the need for an HTML parser I am more looking for information about which elements and attributes would require the browser to load additional resources.