# How does browser detect embedded web content from a HTML page?

Tags: browser, tags, hyperlink

Once a browser gets the main html page, how does it know which are the embedded content should be request again from web server, and which are only external links? Is it based on type of tags, e.g ?

If so, could someone give me a reference of what these tags are?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML5 spec defines the element category "[Embedded content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#embedded-content-0)":

> **Embedded content** is content that imports another resource into the document, or content from another vocabulary that is inserted into the document.

It lists the following elements:

- `audio`
- `canvas`
- `embed`
- `iframe`
- `img`
- `math`
- `object`
- `svg`
- `video`

---

Elements like `link` or `script` (both in [Metadata category](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#metadata-content-0)) can also refer to other ressources that user-agents (browsers, screen-readers, …) are free to link to or include or do whatever they want to do with it. For example, browsers like Firefox or Chromium will (by default) load and "apply" CSS that is linked within the `link` element, that has the `rel` value = `stylesheet`. Browsers like Lynx or w3m won't do that. They simply ignore that link.

---

For `link`, HTML5 [states](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-link-element.html#the-link-element) which link types "are links to resources that are to be used to augment the current document, generally automatically processed by the user agent":

> Two categories of links can be created using the `link` element: **Links to external resources** and hyperlinks. The [link types section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes) defines whether a particular link type is an external resource or a hyperlink.

---

Maybe also consider the `style` attribute (for inline CSS), which could include a `background-image` `url`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am now trying to locate all the  resource to be downloaded from html page. So, I probably need to know all the possible elements/embedded content, which require Firefox/Chromiun, for example, to load new resources. Do you have any reference, or where could I possibly find these information?

Comment: I added info about which link types link to resources that the browsers typically might want to process.

Comment: @Le Wang: I think this depends on the kind of user-agent. Probably even browsers like Firefox and Chromium have some differences, especially if you consider add-ons that might make use of e.g. other link types. Per HTML5 spec, the list of elements mentioned in my answer should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the tags help browser identify the resources to load. After downloading/retrieving the content the browser determines what to do with the content based on the content-type header in the response.

Comment: Assuming the browser only has the html page, it somehow needs to know what are just external links and what are the web objects to be downloaded, e.g. js, css, img. After downloading the objects, the browser checks the content-type from HTTP response header, however, I want to know how the browser determines which objects to download beforehand.

Comment: That is where html compliance and scripting support comes into picture. Eg: if a particular version of firefox supports html5 and additional javascript constructs, what it means is that it understands the content within the tags as in the spec and the attributes of tags. If the tags need a new resource to be downloaded for rendering, the browser will download so and use the resource. If it doesn't understand a tag, the browser will ignore the tag and its content.